# Get battery temperature [KOTLIN]

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, kotlin

I'm working on a small project where I launch my app and then want to show the battery temperature in a toast.

I do this with a broadcast receiver.

When I start the app everything goes well but no toast I have the idea that ExampleBroadcastReceiver does not open?

When I put a log in the onReceive I don't see a message.

This is my code, what am I doing wrong?

**ExampleBroadcastReceiver.kt**

```
class ExampleBroadcastReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {

    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        if(intent.action == "android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED"){
            val temp = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_TEMPERATURE,0) / 10.0
            Toast.makeText(context, "${temp}", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.kt**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    }
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<receiver android:name=".ExampleBroadcastReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: Implicit broadcast receivers declared in manifest do not work since android Oreo. You need to have a receiver in activity or a service and keep your app alive to receive updates.

Comment: @Pawel Thanks for your message. If the broadcast doesn't work when an app is closed, can you explain to me how people update something like this: https://imgur.com/a/cMyFpsA without the app open? What do they use?

Answer (score 0):

You almost got it right. Reading from your code, I see that you did not register your broadcast receiver in your activity.

```
    class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    
        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
             super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
             setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val exampleBroadcastReceiver = ExampleBroadcastReceiver()
        this.registerReceiver(exampleBroadcastReceiver, IntentFilter(
            Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED
        )) 


    }
}
```

It should work. Until you register your broadcast, it won't be called. Broadcast receivers use Observer patterns, which means you need to register yourself to observe the events. Please comment below, if it does not still work.